# How do you run an unix executable file in main

Tags: haskell

I am familiar with the basic concepts of haskell but have scant experience doing "real" stuff with it. So now I have a unix executable file and I would like to play with it in ghci and eventually run it in main. The file outputs a bunch of stuff in CSV format, so I would like to run it and do stuff with the output. So far I can open the file:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let path = "pathToFile/myFile"
    yes      <- doesFileExist path
    file     <- if yes then readFile path else return ""
    print "ok!"
```

But file is `String` typed, which is not really what I want. So I am not very familiar with what libraries I should use next. Please point me in a direction (documentation, blogs, etc) that deals with this kind of stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Look into [`System.Process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.1.0.1/docs/System-Process.html).

Comment: No, `file` has type `String`, not `IO String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`proc`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:proc) from [`System.Process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.1.0.1/docs/System-Process.html). To run the script with no arguments, try

```
main = do
    let path = "..."
    (Just stdin, Just stdout, Just stderr, p) 
      <- createProcess $ proc path []
    putStrLn $ hgetContents stdout
```

This will print the output of your script (assuming there is any). Here, `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are all `Handle`s representing the various channels, which can then be used to pipe output between processes. For more information on manipulating the processes, take a look at the [`System.Process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.1.0.1/docs/System-Process.html) documentation. For more information on manipulating the `Handle`s, jump on over to [`GHC.IO.Handle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/GHC-IO-Handle.html).

The above is a somewhat primitive method, but it is very generic and should work for most purposes. However, the [`System.Process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.1.0.1/docs/System-Process.html) library contains many shortcuts for common problems. As melpomene pointed out in his answer, the simpler [`readProcess`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:readProcess) function should be sufficient for what you wanted to do in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way to run a program and get its output is to use [`readProcess` from `System.Process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:readProcess):

```
import System.Process (readProcess)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let prog = "pathToFile/myExecutable"
    output <- readProcess prog [] ""
    putStrLn ("The output was: " ++ show output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally use `rawSystem` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:rawSystem from System.Process.

Here is it's example use in code of my own https://github.com/urbanslug/wai-devel/blob/master/src/Main.hs#L23

It takes the command and a list of arguments.

Here is it's description from hackage

rawSystem :: String -> [String] -> IO ExitCode Source

*The computation rawSystem cmd args runs the operating system command cmd in such a way that it receives as arguments the args strings exactly as given, with no funny escaping or shell meta-syntax expansion. It will therefore behave more portably between operating systems than system.
The return codes and possible failures are the same as for system.*